How to prevent abuse of Google Play subscriptions tied to different Firebase accounts in my Android app?
I'm using the Google Play Billing Library in my Android app, and everything works fine during testing. However, I encountered a potential issue with the subscription model when integrating it with Firebase.
Here’s the scenario:

A user subscribes to a product using their Google account.
The subscription is successfully acknowledged, and the app allows them access to certain premium features.
My app also uses Firebase Authentication, where users log in with Firebase accounts (e.g., email/password, Google Sign-In).
The app enforces daily usage limits for some premium features, such as generating cover letters, which are stored in Firestore and depend on whether the Firebase user is subscribed.

The problem:
Subscriptions are tied to Google accounts, but usage limits are tied to Firebase accounts.
A user could abuse this by:

Subscribing with one Google account.
Logging into the app with multiple Firebase accounts while using the same subscribed Google account.
Resetting their usage limits for premium features each time they switch Firebase accounts.

Here’s how I currently check the subscription status:
billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(params) { billingResult, purchases ->
    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        purchases.any { it.purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED && it.isAcknowledged }
    }
}

Question:
How can I prevent users from abusing the subscription system by creating multiple Firebase accounts tied to the same Google account? Is there a way to enforce limits or link subscriptions directly to Firebase accounts while keeping them tied to Google accounts for billing purposes?
Additional Notes:
I understand that subscriptions are tied to Google accounts, which makes this challenging.
I’m looking for a best practice to ensure the limits stored in Firestore are enforced across Firebase accounts for the same Google account.
The premium features are directly linked to the subscription status, but the limits are reset when switching Firebase accounts.
Any suggestions or approaches to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

What exactly does this mean: "Creating multiple Firebase accounts to bypass the limits tied to a single Firebase account"?  What limits are you talking about, and how do those limits relate to Google Play subscriptions (since Play subscriptions are tied to Google accounts, not Firebase accounts)?  I suggest editing the question to explain in more detail what it is that you are personally able to do that you don't want others to be able to replicate.  Maybe you should only accept Firebase accounts that use Google for auth and nothing else, then no new accounts will be able to "share" resources.

@DougStevenson, I've edited the question. I've thought about accepting accounts created using only Google, but I don't think that's the best practice.

As long as you allow people to use their signed in Google account completely separate from any Firebase account, you will not be able to resolve this problem to your satisfaction.  Someone will always be able to create as many Firebase accounts as they want (within limits) while also staying signed in to their Google account.
As I mentioned in comments, the only way to reliably defend against this is to only allow Firebase accounts signed up with a Google auth provider.  This is not a matter of "best practice", it's a matter of your app's requirements.  If your app's requirements say that only Google-authenticated users can also create Firebase account using the Google credentials, then that is what you can implement.  Do what makes sense.  This is the whole reason why you get to choose which auth providers are allowed in a Firebase product.
If you wish to allow people to create Firebase accounts without having a Google account, then you must ask yourself: "Why do I allow this? What is the use case?"  You haven't sufficiently explained that in your question, so I can't make comment on that.  But if there really must not be a true 1:1 relationship between Firebase auth and Google auth, then you need to:

Create some product-based rules to determine what a non-Google Firebase account is actually allowed to do
Come up with a way to enforce those rules.

A full discussion of this is outside the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. You will likely need to defer the enforcement of these rules to some backend you control so that someone can not simply decide to bypass them by hacking your frontend code.  There is plenty of support for backend management of Firebase Auth by way of the Firebase Admin SDK.
Also keep in mind that you can enable someone to link their Google account to their existing Firebase account as needed.
